# ZF2 fromQuery() returns an empty array

Tags: php, nginx, zend-framework2

I'm just starting to get going with Zend framework 2 and this seems like a simple task, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I'm trying to simply get the query parameters: `controller/action?name=something`

I've tried using:

```
$this->params()->fromQuery()
$this->plugin('params')->fromQuery();
```

Which I believe both are the same, however both return empty arrays when I have parameters set.

My route looks like this:

```
        'users' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/users/search',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Module\Controller\Users',
                    'action'     => 'search',
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        'type' => 'Query',
                    ),
                ),
            ),   
        ),
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the Params plugin [listed on this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html).

You could try (I'm pulling this from the plugin's code. $param should be `null`, actually):

```
$this->getController()->getRequest()->getQuery($param, $default)->toArray();
```

`fromQuery()` is simply a wrapper for the above (see it on [line 88 here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/Params.php)), though so if that didn't work for you this might not (unless the problem is with the plugin not being loaded or instantiated correctly):

```
$this->params()->fromQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, so within the controller I used `$this->getRequest()->getQuery()->toArray()`, but no dice.  I'm thinking now this is probably a config issue with nginx :\

Comment: That's possible since your initial attempt with `$this->params()->fromQuery();` really should have worked.

Comment: Yeah, well I'll tool with it tomorrow and update here if that resolved things.

Comment: Good luck. I actually just started using ZF2 for a largish project so any ZF2 tips you can add to the SO heap are appreciated. Oh, and you just pushed me over 5,000 reputation... thanks for that, woo hoo!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, that you have a problem at your nginx config.

Just add `$is_args$args` to `location /` section:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

And restart nginx `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Comment: Google, stackoverflow and your answer = great! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_request->getParam('name');
```

I think this will work..

Comment: That was not defined and getParam is not part of the request object, however I did try: `$request = new Request(); $request->getQuery()` but no avail